# Fetch the updated price?

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://roroshetta.no/produkter/rett-vegg/orion/

When selecting a option from all the select menus, selecting "Børstet kobber" in the "Metall / Farge / PVD-belegg / Høyglans farger" menu. How can i catch the updated price which gets added to the page?

Its not my website, so i need to inject a javascript/jquery with a chrome extention and alert the updatet price.

Iam using the cjs extention for chrome, but need help with the javascript/jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

This site using a call to a PHP page to query for prices when you enter you selections. If you go look in the Network tab in the Developer tools, you can see the calls being made.

You can see where the request is going and what parameters are.

[image]

Here's a copy of my request as a `fetch`

```
fetch("https://roroshetta.no/?wc-ajax=get_variation", {"credentials":"include","headers":{},"referrer":"https://roroshetta.no/produkter/rett-vegg/orion/","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","body":"attribute_bredde=60+cm&attribute_hoyde=64+cm&attribute_ventilasjonstype=Ekstern+motor&attribute_metall-farge-pvd-belegg-hoyglans-farger=B%C3%B8rstet+kobber&product_id=56613","method":"POST","mode":"cors"});
```

This returned the response

```
{"attributes":{"attribute_bredde":"60 cm","attribute_hoyde":"64 cm","attribute_ventilasjonstype":"","attribute_metall-farge-pvd-belegg-hoyglans-farger":"B\u00f8rstet kobber"},"availability_html":"","backorders_allowed":false,"dimensions":{"length":"","width":"","height":""},"dimensions_html":"I\/A","display_price":16680,"display_regular_price":16680,"image":{"title":"Orion01","caption":"","url":"https:\/\/roroshetta.no\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/Orion01.jpg","alt":"Orion01","src":"https:\/\/roroshetta.no\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/Orion01.jpg","srcset":"https:\/\/roroshetta.no\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/Orion01.jpg 1280w, https:\/\/roroshetta.no\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/Orion01-300x265.jpg 300w, https:\/\/roroshetta.no\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/Orion01-768x679.jpg 768w, https:\/\/roroshetta.no\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/Orion01-1024x906.jpg 1024w","sizes":"(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px","full_src":"https:\/\/roroshetta.no\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/Orion01.jpg","full_src_w":1280,"full_src_h":1132,"thumb_src":"https:\/\/roroshetta.no\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/Orion01.jpg","thumb_src_w":300,"thumb_src_h":265,"src_w":600,"src_h":531},"image_id":"59948","is_downloadable":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_purchasable":true,"is_sold_individually":"no","is_virtual":false,"max_qty":"","min_qty":1,"price_html":"<span class=\"price\"><ins class=\"h2\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#107;&#114;&nbsp;16.680 <small class=\"woocommerce-price-suffix\">inkl. mva.<\/small><\/ins><\/span>","sku":"1350 + 8506","variation_description":"","variation_id":62991,"variation_is_active":true,"variation_is_visible":true,"weight":"","weight_html":"I\/A","image_link":"https:\/\/roroshetta.no\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/Orion01.jpg","image_src":"https:\/\/roroshetta.no\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/09\/Orion01.jpg","uncode_image_path":"2017\/09\/Orion01.jpg","image_sizes":"","image_srcset":""}
```

You'll need to be familiar with `Promise`s to get the data from the returned stream

Comment: I also found that in the inspector, but did not figure out how to catch the display_price into my injected jquery code. Is this even possible? Or do i need to catch all the selects and make my own request to the https://roroshetta.no/?wc-ajax=get_variation url?